# Find chain of columns values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, common-table-expression

Table:

```
create table tbl_test
(
    col1 int,
    col2 int
);
```

Records:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_test VALUES(111,112),
                            (112,113),
                            (113,114),
                            (114,111),
                            (115,116),
                            (117,118),
                            (118,119),
                            (111,130),
                            (120,121),
                            (122,123),
                            (123,111),
                            (124,111);
```

**Query**: I want to find the complete chain col1 and col2 in the form of `111->112->113->114->111` 
(This is complete chain because it starts with `111` and end with `111`).

Expected Output 2:

```
col1    col2
-------------
111     112
112     113
113     114
114     111
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are more details here in order to understand it easier. First of all, we are going to use a recursive [common table expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#guidelines-for-defining-and-using-recursive-common-table-expressions). Then, we need to know the `start value` for each group in order to know when to `stop` the recursion. In your case this is the minimum value of `col01`, but we can have many `start` values, so I've added a group id - you can use it to filter the final results.

```
WITH DataSource AS
(
    SELECT col1
          ,col2
          ,0 as level
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Col1, col2) AS [groupID]
          ,0 as anchorMatched
          ,col1 as startValue
    FROM tbl_test
    WHERE col1 IN (SELECT MIN(col1) FROM tbl_test)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT A.col1
          ,A.col2
          ,level + 1
          ,B.[groupID]
          ,anchorMatched + CASE WHEN A.col1 = B.col2 AND A.col2 = B.startValue THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
          ,b.startValue
    FROM tbl_test A
    INNER JOIN DataSource B
        ON A.col1 = B.col2
    WHERE (anchorMatched = 0 AND A.col1 <> B.startValue)
)
SELECT *
FROM DataSource
WHERE groupID = 1;
```

[image]

Comment: What change is need to be done if I found another chain for example `117->118->119->117`?

Comment: @MAK Sure you can. That's why you have group IDs. You need just to identify these values in the first select.