# Find chain of columns values - Follow-Up

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, common-table-expression, recursive-query

This is the follow-up question of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51237878/find-chain-of-columns-values).

Table:

```
create table tbl_test
(
    col1 int,
    col2 int
);
```

Records:

**edited**:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_test VALUES(111,112),
                            (112,113),
                            (113,114),
                            (114,111),
                            (115,116),
                            (117,118),
                            (118,119),
                            (119,117), --Added
                            (111,130),
                            (120,121),
                            (122,123),
                            (123,111),
                            (124,111);
```

**Query**: I want to find the complete chain col1 and col2 in the form of `111->112->113->114->111` 
(This is complete chain because it starts with `111` and end with `111`).

**Note**: There might be multiple chain in the table.

Expected Output 2:

```
col1    col2
-------------
111     112
112     113
113     114
114     111 
117     118
118     119  
119     117
```

Tried with gotqn's answer:

```
WITH DataSource AS
(
    SELECT col1
          ,col2
          ,0 as level
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Col1, col2) AS [groupID]
          ,0 as anchorMatched
          ,col1 as startValue
    FROM tbl_test
    WHERE col1 IN (SELECT MIN(col1) FROM tbl_test)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT A.col1
          ,A.col2
          ,level + 1
          ,B.[groupID]
          ,anchorMatched + CASE WHEN A.col1 = B.col2 AND A.col2 = B.startValue THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
          ,b.startValue
    FROM tbl_test A
    INNER JOIN DataSource B
        ON A.col1 = B.col2
    WHERE (anchorMatched = 0 AND A.col1 <> B.startValue)
)
SELECT *
FROM DataSource
WHERE groupID = 1;
```

But unable to get the second chain.

Comment: The records seem to represent edges of a graph, and it seems that your "complete" chains are circles. Obviously, edges are not restricted to the type (x, x+1) and those that finally "complete" a chain, as the edge (111, 130) shows. Are there any restrictions the apply to the records and to the possible "complete chains" like "all but one edges in a complete contain increasing nodes"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
WITH DataSource AS
(
    SELECT col1
          ,col2
          ,0 as level
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Col1, col2) AS [groupID]
          ,0 as anchorMatched
          ,col1 as startValue
    FROM tbl_test
    WHERE col1 IN (Select col2 from tbl_test where (col2-col1)<>1 )
    UNION ALL
    SELECT A.col1
          ,A.col2
          ,level + 1
          ,B.[groupID]
          ,anchorMatched + CASE WHEN A.col2 = B.startValue THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
          ,b.startValue
    FROM tbl_test A
    INNER JOIN DataSource B
        ON A.col1 = B.col2
    WHERE (anchorMatched = 0 AND A.col1 <> B.startValue AND (A.col2 = A.col1 +1 or A.col2 = B.startValue))
)
SELECT *
FROM DataSource where groupID in (SELECT groupID FROM DataSource where anchorMatched = 1)
order by col1,groupID
```

Comment: What if the col2 value in the fourth row is changed fom 111 to 112 (so the first "chain" should be 112 -> 113 -> 114 -> 112)?

Comment: @WolfgangK Good catch! It would've gone into infinite loop. Edited my answer.

Comment: @WolfgangK Yeah. Nothing should happen

Comment: Well, if you know that 111 -> 130 -> 123 -> 111 is not a chain, then you know more than I do. :-)

Comment: Well, I guess I do then. Not a "chain" as defined by OP.

Comment: Please shed a little light on my head (and maybe the head of others) and point me/us to the definition in the OP that shows that this was not a chain.